# Blazor WebAssembly - WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:51489/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly project which I start locally by using `dotnet watch run`. When I do this, I get the following output:

```
C:\dev\BlazorRater\BlazorRater.UI [master ≡ +1 ~5 -1 !]> dotnet watch run
watch : Started
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\dev\BlazorRater\BlazorRater.UI
```

In the browser console, the following gets logged on the initial load:

```
Debugging hotkey: Shift+Alt+D (when application has focus)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 blazor Loaded 8.87 MB resourcesThis application was built with linking (tree shaking) disabled. Published applications will be significantly smaller.
(index):28 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:51489/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ (index):28
```

When I make a change to a .razor, .razor.css, or .cs, the browser doesn't automatically reload.

If I then do a Ctrl+F5 to reload my app, I do **not** get the WebSocket connection failure in the console:

```
Debugging hotkey: Shift+Alt+D (when application has focus)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 blazor Loaded 8.87 MB resourcesThis application was built with linking (tree shaking) disabled. Published applications will be significantly smaller.
```

and now when I make a change to a .razor, .razor.css, or .cs file the browser **will** automatically reload with my changes.

Why on initial load am I getting a WebSocket error, but don't when I perform a Ctrl+F5? Also, a Ctrl+R does not solve the WebSocket issue. Only a Ctrl+F5 fixes it.